# Validar Caracteres contraseña Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, regex, validación

recurro de nuevo a ustedes... Intento validar que la contraseña ingresada tenga como minimo dos (2) de los siguientes caracteres especiales `*?¡!#$%&` , ya lo he intentado con regex y no me funciona, lo intenté recorriendo la longitud de la contraseña con un `for` letra a letra y cuando pongo el condicional para evaluar la letra, la aplicación se bloquea hasta que se detiene sola. Si que me muestra la letra que recorre, con un `Toast`, pero no se que pasa que al comparar con el caracter con un `if` la aplicación se bloquea y no responde. Esta es una de las formas que lo he intentado...

```
public void validarPassword(View v) {

        String txtPassword = etPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (txtPassword.isEmpty()) {
            etPassword.setError("Campo obligatorio");

        } else if (txtPassword.length() > 10) {
            etPassword.setError("Demasiados caracteres");

        } else {

            boolean okpassword = false;
            int contador = 0;

            while (!okpassword) {
                for(int i=0; i <txtPassword.length(); i++){
                    char posicion = txtPassword.charAt(i);
                    String letra = String.valueOf(posicion);

//Hasta aqui recorre letra a letra y me funciona si la muestro con un Toast, pero al poner el condicional ya la aplicación no funciona, se bloquea hasta que se detiene.

                    if (letra == "$" || letra == "?" || letra == "¡" || letra == "!") {
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                if(contador <2 ){
                    okpassword = false;
                }else {
                    okpassword = true;
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contraseña válida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

otra forma en que lo intenté fue hacerlo de la siguiente forma....

```
private boolean validarPassword() {
        int caracteres = 0;
        boolean okpassword= false;
        String txtPassword = etPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (txtPassword.isEmpty()) {
            etPassword.setError("Campo obligatorio");
            return false;
        } else if (txtPassword.length() > 10) {
            etPassword.setError("Demasiados caracteres");
            return false;
        } else {            

            for (int i = 0; i < txtPassword.length(); i++) {
                String letra = String.valueOf(i);

//valido que el o los caracteres ingresados sean de acuerdo a los establecidos y no diferentes
                if (!letra.matches("(?=.*[*?¡!#$%&])")) { 
                    etPassword.setError("Sin caracter especial reconocido");
                    okpassword = false;
                }else {
                    etPassword.setError(null);                    
                    caracteres ++;
                }
                if (caracteres < 2) {
                    etPassword.setError("Incluya al menos dos caracteres especiales");
                    okpassword = false;
                }else {
                    okpassword = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!okpassword == false){
                etPassword.setError(null);
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Agradezco si me pueden apoyar con sus respuestas para saber en que me estoy equivocando, soy estudiante apenas y pues lo he hecho basado en foros que he encontrado sobre el tema. La mayoría de foros hablan es para validar que tenga al menos 1 carácter especial, yo necesito validar que tenga como mínimo 2 caracteres especiales.

Comment: ¿Probaste usando el contains? Ejemplo: `if(tuString.contains($) || tuString.contains(""/) etc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, no se porque usas un `while`, no termino de entender esa parte pero lo que hice fue quitarlo y modificar tu `else` de la siguiente manera:

```
        int contador = 0;

        for(int i=0; i <txtPassword.length(); i++){
            char posicion = txtPassword.charAt(i);
            String letra = String.valueOf(posicion);
            if (letra.contains("$") || letra.contains("?") || letra.contains("¡")|| letra.contains("!")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), letra, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                contador++;
                if(contador <2 ){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La contraseña debe contener caracteres especiales", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contraseña válida: " + letra, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Ahora, solo debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades pueso que el código que hice muestra en el `Toast` cada caracter especial que se ingresó.

Comment: Excelente @FranqoBalsamo muy de apoyo tu respuesta, en realidad lo adapté a mi proyecto, solo saqué el ``` If ``` que evalúa el contador, y lo puse fuera del ``` For ```, hice la prueba y funciona de maravilla, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Asi puedes hacer la validacion de carateres especiles con Pattern. java.util.regex

Patrón final estático privado
PASSWORD_PATTERN =

```
       Patrón.compile ("^" +

               “(? =. * [@ # $% ^ & + =])” + // al menos 1 carácter especial

               “(? = \\ S + $)” + // sin espacios en blanco

               ". {4,}" + // al menos 4 caracteres

               PS
```

Tomado de https://es.acervolima.com/como-validar-una-contrasena-usando-expresiones-regulares-en-android/